# Replace Exact Occurrence of Word in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to repeatedly remove certain stop words from articles. Currently I am using the function str_replace to achieve this. As the first argument I use the stop list array variable to remove any occurrence of the stop words. This works fine except that it also removes any matches that occur in middle of a word (i.e, if the stop words is "th" it would remove "th" from "the", "then" etc).

Now if I would have supplied the argument using plain text I could add a space on either side of the word to remedy the situation. However since i am using a variable array this won't work. I also tried using the concatenate operator, however this doesn't seem to be a legal connector inside a function.

Current code looks something like this:

```
$i = str_replace(" " . $swarray . " ", $string );
```

Comment: "Stop word" normally presumes that you want to search in this text and don't really care about the actual text as such. Is that assumption correct? In that case, I'd use a radically different approach using `strtok` and clearing out array elements afterwards (or... not adding them at all if they match). That's many times faster than cutting substrings out of a large string one by one.

Comment: Well yes I would like to search and do other things with the text as if the stop words didn't exist..

Comment: For "other things", you may need the complete text without stop words, but for searching, I'd say it's more efficient to `strtok` the text into an array and throw away the stop words. Removing many small bits and pieces from a large string repeatedly copies around HUGE amounts of memory.

Answer (score 13):

You need to instead use [**`preg_replace`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with word boundaries. For example below we're only replacing word `the` while avoiding replacing `them` or `then` etc

```
$string = preg_replace('/\bthe\b/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I replace "the" w an array variable? If not it defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: @user1926567: Yes you can use arrays in preg_replace. See `Example #2` in http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: My current syntax is:                                                   $i = preg_replace('/\b$swarray\b/', '', $string);                                                        However this just returns the original string when I echo it.

Comment: Actually you need to wrap `\b` in each element of your pattern array. Please see examples on linked page carefully.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid as this would be very tedious.

Comment: tedious? Why so? A single one lines array_map command does that for you.

Answer (score 6):

`preg_replace` with `array`

```
$find = array('/\bth\b/', '/\bthe\b/', '/\bthen\b/');
$replace = array('', '', '');

echo $i = preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

#### Or

```
$find = array('/\bth\b/', '/\bthe\b/', '/\bthen\b/');

echo $i = preg_replace($find, "", $string);
```

Regex match document: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#89364

```
\b Match a word boundary
```

Comment: You're close, but your answer would result in 2 spaces whenever the target word is between two other words.

Comment: Maybe add `preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$string);`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$i = $string;
foreach($swarray as $word) {
  $i = str_replace(" " . $word . " ", "", $i );
}
```

Comment: What about when the word if first or last?