# How can I find SPECIFIC TEXT FIELD in wordpress theme and replace with own

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This is to inform you that I am working on a wordpress theme named, **houzez** where some fields are properties, agent and agencies. Apart from these there is a search bar which contains a text field placeholder (where written Enter Keyword…) along with some drop-down option such as countries, city, property type, property status. Now I wish to make some changes as I am making a website for Educational Constant agencies where will be many universities and their courses by countries. I wish to make changes as follows:

Property - Course.
Agent - University/Institution.
Agencies - Countries.
In the search bar, Countries and Cities will remain same. But I want make changes as follows:
All types - Course Type.
All Status - Subject Area.

For reference, my wesite: http://www.eoe.gipcl.org.uk

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can help with part of this but not sure I completely understand the  the goal for the search bar. If you are trying to have the default words display as different words, there is a snippet of code I have used in the past.  You would place the code in a file labeled 'functions.php' within the child theme folder. If you are not using a child theme, you would append it to your themes "functions.php" probably unless someone gives you better advice on that. I only put in two lines to change below but you can add more.  Here is the script:

```
    /* Replace Text */

    add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text'); 
    add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

    function translate_text($translated) { 
    $translated = str_ireplace('Agencies', 'Countries', $translated); 
$translated = str_ireplace('Agent', 'University/Institution', $translated); 
    return $translated; 
    }
```

Hoping this helps you get closer to all that you are trying to accomplish.  Just not sure I completely understand the second part of your question.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I really appreciate for your support :)

Comment: Dear @Waterwalk77

Now I have got few more small problems. 

1. I would like to get changes Property to Course and Property Status to Subject Area. Therefore, I have inserted following into function.php but it is conflicting with each other; rest of them are fine.


$translated = str_ireplace('Property', 'Course', $translated);
$translated = str_ireplace('Property Status', 'Subject Area', $translated);

How Can I keep both Field? please

Comment: HI Sayed, sorry I was offline for a couple of weeks with all the busyness of holidays. It's kind of hard to read your code like that. Is there any chance you can post the whole added section that you are using in 'functions.php' (just the part you added) so I can see it better?

Comment: I'm still new so I couldn't add to my reply above but I think this post might help you if I understand your issue correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442492/replace-exact-occurrence-of-word-in-php

Comment: Dear @Waterwalk77

Hope you are doing well. I really appreciate for your support. Have a great day :)